# C return big number confusion

Tags: c, char

When I input the string instead of `y` or `n` in this code, it will return the large number.

So I want to know how to fix it.

My first thought is that if I input the string instead of this,
it will return to the first paragraph and run again.

But when I trying to use this, it will return and run again.

But It will save the string and change it into an ASCII code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>;
#include <stdio.h>;
int main() {
    int num = 1; //設置迴圈變數
    int change; //設置可變動變數
    int count=0; // 跑了幾次
    char ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,ans6,ans7 ; //答案共7個
    int final_ans = 0;//最後答案
    printf("thinking a number on your mind, and I will guess it!\n\n");



first:
    for(num=1; num<=100; num+=2) {
        ++count;
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    count = 0;//清空變數
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans1);
    if((ans1=='Y') || (ans1=='y')) { //若有數字
        final_ans += 1;
    }
second:
    for(num=2; num<=100; num+=2) {
        change = num;
        ++count;
        if(count%2==0) {
            change--;
        }
        printf("%-4.2d", change);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans2);
    count = 0;//清空變數
    change = 0;//清空變數
    if((ans2=='Y') || (ans2=='y')) {
        final_ans += 2;
    }
third:
    for(num=4; num<=100; num++) {
        change = num;
        ++count;
        if(count%4==1&&num!=4) {
            num+=4;
        }
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans3);
    count = 0;//清空變數
    change = 0;//清空變數
    if((ans3=='Y') || (ans3=='y')) {
        final_ans +=4;
    }
fourth:
    for(num=8; num<=100; num++) {
        change = num;
        ++count;
        if(count%8==1&&num!=8) {
            num+=8;
        }
        if(num>100) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans4);
    count = 0;//清空變數
    change = 0;//清空變數
    if((ans4=='Y') || (ans4=='y')) {
        final_ans += 8;
    }
fifth:
    for(num=16; num<=100; num++) {
        change = num;
        ++count;
        if(count%16==1&&num!=16) {
            num+=16;
        }
        if(num>100) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans5);
    count = 0;//清空變數
    change = 0;//清空變數
    if((ans5=='Y') || (ans5=='y')) {
        final_ans += 16;
    }
sixth:
    for(num=32; num<=100; num++) {
        change = num;
        ++count;
        if(count%32==1&&num!=32) {
            num+=32;
        }
        if(num>100) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans6);
    count = 0;//清空變數
    change = 0;//清空變數
    if((ans6=='Y') || (ans6=='y')) {
        final_ans += 32;
    }
seventh:
    for(num=64; num<=100; num++) {
        ++count;
        printf("%-4.2d", num);//4格寬 數字顯示2位
        if(count%9==0) {
            printf("\n");//每執行9次換行
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Is your number on the table (y/n)? \n");
    scanf("%s", &ans7);
    if((ans7=='Y') || (ans7=='y')) {
        final_ans += 64;
    }

    else if((ans1=='n') || (ans1=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto second;//回到第二個table
    } else if((ans2=='n') || (ans2=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto third;//回到第三個table
    } else if((ans3=='n') || (ans3=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto fourth;//回到第四個table
    } else if((ans4=='n') || (ans4=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto fifth;//回到第五個table
    } else if((ans5=='n') || (ans5=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto sixth;//回到第六個table
    } else if((ans6=='n') || (ans6=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
        goto seventh;//回到第七個table
    } else if((ans7=='n') || (ans7=='N')) { //若無數字
        final_ans += 0;
    }



    if(final_ans<=100) { //判斷最後答案
        printf("your secret number is %d",final_ans);
    } else if(final_ans>100) {
        printf("WRONG!%d is not a number form 1~100",final_ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &ans1);` The `%s` format is for strings. `%c` is a single char. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I suggest making a function such as `bool get_yn(void)` that reads the `y` or `n` answer and returns a boolean. That way you don't need to repeat the same code checking for uppercase and lowercase every time. And you can do the reading properly since you only have to do it once, including error checking and skipping whitespace (newlines in particular).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: doing that will get confused by the newlines.  You want `scanf(" %c", &ans1)` -- the space to skip whitespace is key.

Answer (score 1):

you have put `;` after every library please remove that

```
#include <stdlib.h>; // remove the ;
#include <stdio.h>; // remove the ;
```

correct code must be

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

By editing that I got correct answers. it works for me.

**I have think about 73**

output -:

```
thinking a number on your mind, and I will guess it!                                                                  

01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17                                                                                    
19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35                                                                                    
37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53                                                                                    
55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71                                                                                    
73  75  77  79  81  83  85  87  89                                                                                    
91  93  95  97  99                                                                                                    
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
y                                                                                                                     
02  03  06  07  10  11  14  15  18                                                                                    
19  22  23  26  27  30  31  34  35                                                                                    
38  39  42  43  46  47  50  51  54                                                                                    
55  58  59  62  63  66  67  70  71                                                                                    
74  75  78  79  82  83  86  87  90                                                                                    
91  94  95  98  99                                                                                                    
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
n            
04  05  06  07  12  13  14  15  20                                                                                    
21  22  23  28  29  30  31  36  37                                                                                    
38  39  44  45  46  47  52  53  54                                                                                    
55  60  61  62  63  68  69  70  71                                                                                    
76  77  78  79  84  85  86  87  92                                                                                    
93  94  95  100                                                                                                       
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
n                                                                                                                     
08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  24                                                                                    
25  26  27  28  29  30  31  40  41                                                                                    
42  43  44  45  46  47  56  57  58                                                                                    
59  60  61  62  63  72  73  74  75                                                                                    
76  77  78  79  88  89  90  91  92                                                                                    
93  94  95                                                                                                            
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
y       
16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24                                                                                    
25  26  27  28  29  30  31  48  49                                                                                    
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58                                                                                    
59  60  61  62  63  80  81  82  83                                                                                    
84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92                                                                                    
93  94  95                                                                                                            
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
n                                                                                                                     
32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40                                                                                    
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49                                                                                    
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58                                                                                    
59  60  61  62  63  96  97  98  99                                                                                    
100                                                                                                                   
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
n                                                                                                                     
64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72                                                                                    
73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81                                                                                    
82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90                                                                                    
91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99                                                                                    
100     
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
n                                                                                                                     
64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72                                                                                    
73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81                                                                                    
82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90                                                                                    
91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99                                                                                    
100                                                                                                                   
Is your number on the table (y/n)?                                                                                    
y                                                                                                                     
your secret number is 73
```